# Cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "findContours" is intended - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, asynchronous

When I try to run the line of code

```
std::future<Mat> fu1 = std::async(std::launch::async, drawContours, colorMask, findContours(colorMask), findContourHierarchy(colorMask, findContours(colorMask)));
```

it displays the error message which I typed in the title? *"Cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "findContours" is intended* . **Why is happening and how do I fix it?** Im fairly new to threading so im not fully sure why this is happening but the thread above it which calls drawBoundingBox works like a charm. Full code below.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace cv;

String filename = "straight7.jpg";


Mat ColorThreshold(String img) {
    Mat ORIGINAL_img, HSV_img, MASKED_img;
    ORIGINAL_img = imread(img, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    dilate(ORIGINAL_img, ORIGINAL_img, 5);
    cvtColor(ORIGINAL_img, HSV_img, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    //erode(HSV_img, HSV_img, 10);
    //dilate(HSV_img, HSV_img, 10);
    inRange(HSV_img, Scalar(80, 150, 15), Scalar(120, 255, 150), MASKED_img);


    return MASKED_img;
}

Mat CannyEdgeDetection(Mat img) {
    int cannylow = 0;
    int cannyhigh = 0;
    Mat BLURRED_img, dst, detectededges;
    GaussianBlur(img, img, Size(5,5), 0);
    Canny(img, detectededges, cannylow, cannyhigh, 3);
    dst = Scalar::all(0);
    img.copyTo(dst, detectededges);

    return dst;
}

void displayConsole(Mat img) {
    namedWindow("Ignore");
}

std::vector<KeyPoint> detectBlobs(Mat img1) {
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    bitwise_not(img1, img1);
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    //Add params below
    params.filterByConvexity = false;
    params.filterByInertia = false;

    Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    detector->detect(img1, keypoints);

    return keypoints;
}

Mat drawBlobs(Mat img, std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints) {
    Mat drawn_blobs;

    drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, drawn_blobs, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    return drawn_blobs;
}

std::vector<std::vector<Point>> findContours(Mat img) {
    std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
    std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    return contours;
}

std::vector<Vec4i> findContourHierarchy(Mat img, std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours) {
    std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    return hierarchy;
}

Mat drawContours(Mat img, std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours, std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy) {
    RNG rng(0);
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 4, hierarchy, 0, Point());

    }

    return drawing;
}

std::vector<Rect> getBoundingBox(std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours) {
    std::vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    }
    return boundRect;
}

Mat drawBoundingBox(Mat img, std::vector<Rect> boundRect) {
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    RNG rng(12345);
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    for (int i = 0; i < boundRect.size(); i++) {
        rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 1, 4, 0);
    }
    return drawing;

}

void main() {
    //Variables
    Mat cannyEdges, colorMask, drawn_blobs, drawn_contours, raw_img, drawn_boundingbox;
    std::vector<Rect> get_boundingbox;
    colorMask = ColorThreshold(filename);
    std::future<Mat> fu = std::async(std::launch::async, drawBoundingBox, colorMask, getBoundingBox(findContours(colorMask)));
    std::future<Mat> fu1 = std::async(std::launch::async, drawContours, colorMask, findContours(colorMask), findContourHierarchy(colorMask, findContours(colorMask)));
    //drawn_contours = drawContours(colorMask, findContours(colorMask), findContourHierarchy(colorMask, findContours(colorMask)));
    //drawn_blobs = drawBlobs(colorMask, detectBlobs(colorMask));
    get_boundingbox = getBoundingBox(findContours(colorMask));

    std::cout << get_boundingbox[1].area() << std::endl;

    imwrite("cannyoutput.jpg", cannyEdges);
    imwrite("colormaskoutput.jpg", colorMask);
    //imwrite("blobout.jpg", drawn_blobs);
    imwrite("contouroutput.jpg", fu1.get());
    imwrite("boundingboxoutput.jpg", fu.get());
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: Don't name your functions the same as OpenCV's and avoid all this confusion.

Comment: Wow yeah, thanks for that. I changed it to displayContours and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @RohanG -- This has nothing to do with threading.  It is a C++ language issue concerning overloaded functions and the compiler determining which to call based on the name only.

Comment: It is ok to name your functions the same as OpenCV's, but is never ok to put them into global namespace or rely on `using namespace` too much.

Comment: anyone else visiting this question your issue might be as silly as forgetting the parentheses after get, e.g `get <0> tpl` instead of `get <0> (tpl)`.